# Problema con entrust role en método login laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

He sobreescrito el metodo login para poder detectar si el usuario verifico su email de forma correcta, pero ahora no puedo efectuar un segundo filtro que es basado en el rol del usuario, antes lo hacia en el metodo authenticated y funcionaba pero desde el metodo login no puedo ejecutar los metodos de verificacion en entrust, este es mi codigo:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $validado = DB::table('users')->where('email', $request->email)->value('confirmed');
    $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->get();


    if ($validado == 1) {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            if($user->hasRole('Admin')) {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/index');
        }
        if ($user->hasRole('Tutor')) {
            return redirect()->intended('tutor/index');
        }

            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Porqué hacces una doble consulta a la base de datos solicitando el mismo usuario? Creería que con una es suficiente.

Comment: En la variable confirmed solo guardo el valor del campo confirmed de la tabla, en la user pues guardo el usuario buscandolo por el usuario que entra en el request, fue la unica forma que se me ocurrio ya que ahi no puedo usar el facade Auth, pero aunque logro traer el usuario, no puedo usar los metodos hasRole.

Comment: Realmente sobra la primera consulta, al obtener todo el usuario en la segunda consulta, simplemente puedes hacer `if ($user->confirmed == 1) ...`

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece al utilizar los métodos `hasRole()`?

Comment: Aparecer el error: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method hasRole does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema parece ser que estás usando `get()` y deberías usar `first()` al momento de usar Eloquent.

```
$user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
```

Si utilizas get(), estás obteniendo una colección de elementos (así sea uno solo el resultado), mientras que si utilizas first(), solo estás obteniendo un elemento.

Comment: Al usar first() ya no me arroja el error anterior, pero no me entra al condicional donde pregunto por el rol y re dirijo, sigue hacia la ruta que por defecto trae osea public/home y a la vista que se muestra ahi

Comment: No entiendo que quieres decir con "no me entra al condicional".

Comment: Ya solucione, aparte del error al no usar [first()] había escrito mal el nombre del rol y por eso se saltaba el condicional donde preguntar por el rol de usuario, muchas gracias.